# Should I show two validation messages for email id in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-experience, usability, web-development-server

I have an email address field on my web application.I have 2 cases for this
a) email should not be empty
b) email should be in proper format .

Whether user keep it empty or put improper email address in the email address
I show only one message "Please enter valid emailid".

My manager says that we should use two validation messages. but I am insisting that this one message is suffiecient.

Please suggest what should be approach for this.

**UPDATED : -**

Here is what I found for Yahoo.com login screen

[image]

[image]

Comment: Their is a property in `errorValidation` is called `Display="Dynamic"` by using this you can show both error in `Asp.Net`

Comment: There may not be one specific answer to this. Usually - If Email field is mandatory it should have that * sign next to it. Leaving it blank should specifically mention that Email field cannot be blank. Then comes the case where user typed something in the field which is not valid email id format. That should be second validation message. Unfortunately - I sound like your Manager :)

Comment: Ok, now what if I use 2 messages. User first submits without inputting an email id . He gets please enter email. Then he enters "abcuser" and submits then he get message as "Please enter valid email" . I am frustating user with 2 messages. Rather than If first time he click for blank input he get to know that he had to type valid email address

Comment: This should probably be asked at https://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth I will Try it on that also

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava What is your say on my opinion above

Comment: @iGod - Please look at my post/answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always good to inform the user of what is happening.If the email is required as per your requirement then you should prompt the user to alert them they cannot leave the email field empty, and also by standards you should accept correct email formats (myemail@something.com). These are both different requirements and should be treated differently for a better user experience. I use [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) for my front end form validations to validate empty text fields and incorrect input formats.

Comment: Ok, now what if I use 2 messages. User first submits without inputting an email id . He gets please enter email. Then he enters "abcuser" and submits then he get message as "Please enter valid email" . I am frustating user with 2 messages. Rather than If first time he click for blank input he get to know that he had to type valid email address

Comment: With libraries like parsley.js the input validation is done on the fly so if i enter a wrong email address once i move to the next field it will trigger the validation message even before i submit the form (good user experience), you can also use a placeholder to guide your users saying "Enter a Valid Email Address johndoe@anonymous.com"

Comment: Thanks Frank. I can show 2 messages with out using library also. But my question is different. It is related to user experience. Should I show 2 messages or my this 1 message is sufficient

Comment: in my opinion i think they are two separate requirements and should be handled separately so i will go for 2 as your boss says.

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it is suitable for you, you can do it by jquery

```
<input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="Email ID">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and use below jquery method for validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').click(function() {
        var EmailID = $('#emailid').val();
        if ($.trim(EmailID).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(EmailID)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();         
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(EmailID ) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(EmailID)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @M.Y.Mnu . But I want to know about user experience

Comment: you can use placehoder is the best option acccroding to me or display message on textchange at the time of input emailID

Comment: you can display single message on button click according to condition it could be for empty or invalid emailID by using condtion

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found on Google Login;

[image: Without any Text Input]

[image: Invalid Email Inout]

Comment: But if you look at yahoo`s login screen you will find it somewhat similar to mine

Comment: Please see my updated section where I asked the question

Comment: @iGod Cool - I would say its up to your Business to take the call. I would prefer the google way personally.

Answer (score 0):

For input validation, I always ry to be as specific as can be: This is one of the usual user frustration points when filling forms and can cause many user drops.

These kind of strings -such as a placeholder or error messages- can be used as a way to engage with your user and set your platform/website's mood.